# How can I update different values in one column in a single query (PSQL)?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I need to update multiple values in a single column based on a "legend" (for lack of a better word).

Let's say this is my current table (CUSTOMERS)

| Cust_Name | Bank |
| --- | --- |
| William | 01 |
| Harry | 02 |
| John | 05 |
| Jack | 01 |
| Matthew | 03 |

And this is the "legend"

***This legend does not exist in the database it is just used to explain my example. It is just a way to present the corresponding values***

| Bank Number | Bank |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | Chase |
| 02 | BankOfAmerica |
| 03 | JPMorgan |
| 04 | WellsFargo |
| 05 | Citigroup |

I want to update the Customers table to show the name of the Bank instead of the Bank Number.
When I first tried to do this it looked like this :

```
update CUSTOMERS
   set BANK = 'Chase'
   where BANK = '01' ;

update CUSTOMERS
   set BANK = 'BankOfAmerica'
   where BANK = '02' ;
...
```

Which had to be executed line by line.

Does anyone know how I can execute this in one go?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
UPDATE CUSTOMERS
SET BANK = CASE
            WHEN BANK = '01' THEN 'Chase'
            WHEN BANK = '02' THEN 'BankOfAmerica'
            WHEN BANK = '03' THEN 'JPMorgan'
            WHEN BANK = '04' THEN 'WellsFargo'
            WHEN BANK = '05' THEN 'Citigroup'
           END
```

demo in [*db<>fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7c68f7ecc3deba7ad2ad597e8eafce9d)

Comment: Thank you. But I should've been more clear, the legend table doesn't exist in the database and I don't want it to. This was just a way of expressing what I was trying to do which is replace old values with the new corresponding values.

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, you would express this as:

```
update customers c
    set bank = l.bank
    from legend l
    where c.bank = l.bank_no;
```

However, I do not see why you would want to update the actual name.  Why not just use a `join` when you query the table?

EDIT:

Based on your comment, you should *create* the legend table.  In any case, you can create a version just for the query:

```
update customers c
    set bank = l.bank
    from (values ('01', 'Chase'),
                 ('02', 'BankOfAmerica'),
                 ('03', 'JPMorgan'),
                 ('04', 'WellsFargo'),
                 ('05', 'Citigroup')
         ) v(bank_no, bank);
    where c.bank = l.bank_no;
```

Comment: Thank you. But I should've been more clear, the legend table doesn't exist in the database and I don't want it to. This was just a way of expressing what I was trying to do which is replace old values with the new corresponding values.

Answer (score 0):

you can update from a VALUES clause:

```
update customers c
   set bank = v.bank_name
from (
  values 
    ('01', 'Chase'), 
    ('02', 'BankOfAmerica'),
    ('03', 'JPMorgan'),
    ('04', 'WellsFargo'),
    ('05', 'Citigroup')
) as v(bank_number, bank_name)
where v.bank_number = c.bank;
```